# Select a value from a line with body parser Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to select a value form a post message, what i recive is csv data, like this:

```
{ reader_name: '"xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx"',
  mac_address: '"name"',
  line_ending: '\n',
  field_delim: ',',
  field_names: 'antenna_port,epc,first_seen_timestamp,peak_rssi',
  field_values: '1,"000005555666600000000000",1414762247726148,-68\n' }
```

What i want is to for example, for the line field_names and field_values, select an independent value like antenna_port, and 1.

What i was trying was:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
        console.log('Encendido');
        var epc = req.body.field_values;
        console.log("MAC= "+epc);
        res.send('si');
```

But i don't know how to select an individual value from that line.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, how i select an specific value, for example the second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a string. Use `req.body.field_values.split(",")` to get the individual values.

Or if you want to assign a name to it you could do something like:

```
var names = req.body.field_names.split(",");
var values = req.body.field_values.replace("\n", "").split(",");

var result = {};

for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    result[names[i]] = values[i];
}
```

Which would return:

```
{
    antenna_port: "1",
    epc: ""000005555666600000000000"",
    first_seen_timestamp: "1414762247726148",
    peak_rssi: "-68"
}
```